# Angular can't disable $log

Tags: angularjs, logging

I use angular with angular-permission library. Need to disable warnings in  console.

[image: angular logFn]

This component (angular-permission) call angular $log service:
[image: angular-permission]

Tried disable this in config, but warning still shows:

> $logProvider.debugEnabled(false);

Code that invoke log:

```
function permissionMap($log) {
  if (PermPermissionStore.hasPermissionDefinition(privilegeName)) {
    PermPermissionStore.getPermissionDefinition(privilegeName);
      return permission.validatePermission();
    }

    $log.warn('Permission or role ' + privilegeName + ' was not defined.');
}
```

Comment: So...do you have, like, access to the *code* that actually invokes these log statements?

Comment: @Makoto I't angular-permission module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Angularjs Decorators](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide) to modify `$log.warn` like this

```
$provide.decorator('$log', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {              
  $delegate.warn = angular.noop;
  return $delegate;
}]);
```

To disable warn in production use this code in config like this

```
angular.module('app')
 .config(['$logProvider','$provide',
    function($logProvider,$provide) {

        if(isProduction){ //flag to check production here
         $logProvider.debugEnabled(false);
         $provide.decorator('$log', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
            $delegate.warn = angular.noop;
            return $delegate;
         }]);
       }

    }
])
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks. It's perfect

Answer (score 0):

Redefine the console.log function in your javascript.

```
console.log = function() {}
```

Comment: Not working( I put this code in to run block, but warning still posted

Answer (score 0):

I found solution (rewrite default $log.warn function):

> $log.warn = function() {};

Answer (score 0):

From [angular-permission documentation](https://github.com/RafaelVidaurre/angular-permission/wiki/Controlling-access-in-views#suppressing-warnings-for-undefined-permissions), this is right way to do that :

```
  app
  .config(function ($permissionProvider) {
    $permissionProvider.suppressUndefinedPermissionWarning(true);
  })
```